# Nginx docker only finds containers on docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm not sure if that's correct or not but I have an `nginx` on a container that proxies the request to a `Nodejs` app and everything is working fine on a `docker-compose` file with the depends on feature and all that. However now I want to separate them into different docker compose files and then it happens that nginx can't find the upstream `nodejsapp`:

```
2017/11/10 15:21:38 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "nodejsapp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.nodejsapp.conf:8
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "nodejsapp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.nodejsapp.conf:8
```

My configuration for the proxy stuff works but in any case is:

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nodejsapp:4000;
        proxy_set_header X-Remote-Addr $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 1d;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(atom|bmp|bz2|css|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|mid|midi|mp4|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rss|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|woff|xls|xml|zip)$ {
        access_log  off;
        log_not_found   on;
        expires     max;
        proxy_pass  http://nodejsapp:4000;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

If I do docker ps I get this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                          PORTS                                                NAMES
f4d888e6c37d        nginx   "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   3 minutes ago       Restarting (1) 33 seconds ago                                                        nginx
5867ac82e5da        nodejsapp:3.2.0-dev     "pm2-docker proces..."   25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes                   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 43554/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp   nodejsapp
```

I understood that docker containers can reach other containers by the name. Then I inspected the networks I have: `docker network ls`

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
cf9b7ea0a5b7        bridge              bridge              local
549c48fa592a        docker_default      bridge              local
652ffb4094f0        host                host                local
412ed3bbfd01        nginx_default       bridge              local
85a803c70f83        none                null                local
```

And then I `docker network inspect bridge` I can see the `nodejsapp` container among others:

```
"Containers": {
            "5867ac82e5dad7642155a7c3df05c37cd83c1be5a0eb49d55cf5325bfaa7ea4d": {
                "Name": "nodejsapp",
                "EndpointID": "a362d02b083e90bb0acc50a2af8ec5a5f0a9a23a9f0ed2bfb62b1a6c60586fb8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "b272cd07cc1e5c28632cbaf05858cf373b6a13304f69bee5de73fc57e5a3cf79": {
                "Name": "sad_poitras",
                "EndpointID": "c5b1e2389f5da8b9acf4f6c7a13f5d6e09411cd960b9e4dcd8ed38fef2982780",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "ffd171939e534a4749a4d215f52c1add353537e91e4a95d7b752775ee2b4c70f": {
                "Name": "elated_hawking",
                "EndpointID": "eca2709e189d8d5922e1dd5d8c5af14826bd77d5a399b63363e3b07671fb5169",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

And I can see that nginx is not connected to any network however it looks to me it tries to create its own network (`nginx_default`)? Note that I cannot see any container attached to that network, possibly because it's failing on start:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "nginx_default",
        "Id": "412ed3bbfd01336c86473a8d07fe6c444389cac44838552a40d6b7ec7f4c972d",
        "Created": "2017-11-10T15:21:35.2016921Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get the it using the bridge one? Am I doing something else wrong?

**UPDATE**: I have set the nodejsapp to be on the network `nginx_default` and then I got `nginx` to start. However the proxy is not working at all and I get the home screen of `nginx`. My docker compose files after I split it into two different compose files:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: nginx:3.1.0-dev
    ports:
     - "10100:80"
    restart: always
    container_name: nginx
```

My Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN  mkdir /tmp/cache
COPY ./nodejsapp/default.dev.nodejsapp.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.nodejsapp.conf
COPY nginx.dev.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The other docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nodejsapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    image: nodejsapp:3.2.0-dev
    ports:
     - "4000:4000"
    restart: always
    container_name: nodejsapp
```

and the corresponding Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest
COPY dist dist/
COPY process.yml .
CMD ["pm2-docker", "process.yml"]
```

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose files?

Comment: Since they are not part of the same docker network nginx is going to ask DNS for the address of nodejsapp and your DNS server isn't going to know what that means.

Comment: added docker compose files and dockerfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an external network to connect the two containers. But first you must create the network, we'll call it my-network:

```
docker network create my-network
```

Then we need to declare the network in each docker-compose file:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-network
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker creates 2 different and isolated networks if you create 2 docker-compose files. AFAIK, the only way is to create a network and "link" the containers to that network.

So, create a network then use it. See the doc here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network